# Аналог UWF в Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows

Необходимо удалять данные из ряда приложений после перезагрузки ПК. Подскажите, есть ли аналоги UWF для Windows 10 Pro или программы, предоставляющие подобный функционал? Спасибо

Comment: Может проще настроить, например, [Песочницу Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/security/application-security/application-isolation/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview) в которой и запускать нужный софт? Ну а она уже в свою очередь возвращается к "заводскому" состоянию при закрытие окна.

Comment: Подходящие классы программ - `гипервизоры`: Vmware Player, Oracle VirtualBox; `песочницы`: Shadow Defender, Sandboxie.